# Is there any possible point to reloading a Python module immediately?

Tags: python, import, reload

Is there any conceivable point to reloading these modules immediately after importing them?  This is the code that I was reviewing which made me wonder:

```
import time
import sys
import os
import string
import pp
import numpy
import nrrd
reload(nrrd)
import smooth as sm
reload(sm)
import TensorEval2C as tensPP
reload(tensPP)
import TrackFiber4C as trackPP
reload(trackPP)
import cmpV
reload(cmpV)
import vectors as vects
reload(vects)
```

Edit: I suggested that this might make the creation of .pyc files more likely, but several people pointed out that this happens this first time, every time.

Comment: No, `.pyc` files are already created when the module is first imported. Please punch the guy who wrote this, either for writing confusing code that does nothing or for not explaining his weird hack with lots of comments. Also, those are some horrible module names.

Comment: I've inherited a fair bit of this programmer's code; they were pretty new to python at the time, so I typically assume that they didn't know how Python worked when I see crazy or un-Pythonic stuff - but I try to be careful about assuming I always know better.  Variable names are frequently super short, and superfluous line breaks and unnecessary `for i in range(len(list)):` loops abound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I note that the *standard* modules are just imported: it's the other modules that are reloaded. I expect whoever wrote this code wanted to be able to easily reload the whole package (so as to get their latest edits). After putting in all these redundant `reload` calls, the programmer only had to write

```
>>> reload(package)
```

to bring things up to date in the interpreter, instead of having to type

```
>>> reload(package.nrrd)
>>> reload(package.sm)
>>> reload(package.tensPP)
```

etc. So please ignore the suggestion that you commit violence against the programmer who wrote this: they are [far from the only programmer](http://www.indelible.org/ink/python-reloading/) who's had trouble with reloading of dependencies. Just encourage them to move the reloads to a convenience function.

Comment: I'm running an embedded version of Python that (for debugging purposes) reloads the main module, and the main module reloads all the others, to ensure that they're all using the latest version of the code. This means that I can debug the code without having to stop and restart the entire application.

Comment: See the link I gave for a framework which *automatically* reloads dependencies when they change.

Comment: Seems like the most likely reason.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that this does cause something to happen; the obvious example is side-effects that happen on import. For instance, a module could log to a file the time and date of every time it is imported.

There is probably no good reason for this, however.

Answer (score 1):

The .pyc files would be created on the first import, so even that's not a very good reason for this.

Comment: I doubt there's any good reason for this. I sure hope it has some remotely valid reason.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question so as to keep from perpetuating that myth.

Answer (score 0):

What's the execution environment for this code? There exists at least one Python web framework that makes different reload decisions than standard python does, which leads to frustration and confusion when you make a change that doesn't 'take'.