# Purpose of a module importing itself

Tags: python, python-import

I stumbled upon the following code that imports itself at the very beginning of the file, and I was wondering if there's any valid reason for doing this?

```py
#inside file a.py

import a as F; reload(F);
import a_util as auto; reload(auto);

def foo():
    some_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    F.foo()
```

From the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127647/is-there-any-possible-point-to-reloading-a-python-module-immediately), the reload statement is most likely there to be able to easily reload the entire package. But I want to know if there are any advantages for a module to import itself. And in the main function, what exactly are the differences between `foo()` and `F.foo()`?

*There aren't any global variables in `a.py` since that's what most related posts seem to suggest.

Comment: I've never seen it. My best guess is that it can help with tracking the impact of changes in a module when using IPython, which wouldn't naturally reload a module after a change. But i feel I'm stretching the boundaries a bit to make a use-case

Comment: Not sure... I had to put in reloads in my code a long time ago to refresh the constant values referenced from a different static file as I changed them, but looking at the code you have pasted I don't know if that is the reason one would do that

Comment: I have seen a module that imports itself in mypy, but I don't know why this is necessary: https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/0a7cb9422d105c7099fdf4ef6a84765ffdcf3058/mypy/build.py#L765

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source code you quote?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the original author was confused and thought it a good thing to do.

One side effect of the reload is the file gets reprocessed, so if there are any immediately executable statements in the file they will again be executed.   I don't see a particular benefit for doing it but someone might have found an edge case.

a good reference for the behavior of reload is here:
[reload reference](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/reload.html)

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a reason for doing this but it works. You just have to remove `reload` (as from python 3 reload is no longer a builtin) and I also removed `a_util` as I do not know what is in this module and it is not needed for the example.

So importing the `a.py` module in itself and calling it works!

File: a.py

```
import a as F

def foo(drink):
    print(f'bar {drink}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    F.foo('Beer')
    foo('Whiskey')
```

results in:

```
bar Beer
bar Whiskey
```

Further on `reload` and where it may be used. If you work interactively (typing `python` at the prompt) you implement `reload` as follows:

```
>>>from importlib import reload
>>>import a as F
>>>F.foo('Ranja')
>>>bar Ranja
>>>
```

edit you `a.py` file, add a function and save

```
def foobar(drink):
    print(f'foobar {drink}')
```

then go back to you interactive terminal just `reload(F)` and you work with the new `a.py` module

```
>>>reload(F)
>>>F.foobar('some brew')
>>>foobar some brew
>>>F.foo('coffee')
>>>bar coffee
>>>
```

Comment: That doesn't address the reason for someone doing it in the first place

Comment: OP is asking why it's done in this instance and not if it works